# Runtime error: program has stopped responding

Tags: c++, iostream, runtime-error

My program is to calculate the price of resources based on the resources that their neighbors have.

It compiles, but at run-time, it breaks and says that the program has stopped responding.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Resource{
    string resName;
    int amount;
    int price;
    public:
        void set_values(string resName, int amount, int price){resName=resName; amount=amount; price=price;};
        string get_name(){return resName;};
        int get_amount(){return amount;};
        int get_price(){return price;}; 
};

class State{
    string stName;
    Resource resources[5];
    public:
        void set_values(string stName){
            stName=stName;
            Resource r; 
            r.set_values(" ", 0, 0);
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                resources[i] = r;
            }
        };
        string get_name(){return stName;};
        void addResource(string name, int amount, int price){
            Resource r;
            r.set_values(name, amount, price);
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if(resources[i].get_name() == " "){
                    resources[i] = r;
                }
            }
        };
        Resource get_resource(string resource){
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if (resources[i].get_name() == resource){
                    return resources[i];
                }
            }
        };
        bool checkForResource(string resource){
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if (resources[i].get_name() == resource){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

};

class Area{
    State allStates[10][10];
    public:
        void initialize(){
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
                    allStates[i][j].set_values(" ");    
                }
            }   
        };
        void addState(string stateName){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == " ")
                        allStates[row][col].set_values(stateName);
                }   
            }   
        };
        State get_state(string name){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == name)
                        return allStates[row][col];
                }   
            }
        };
        void deleteState(string name){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == name)
                        allStates[row][col].set_values(" ");
                }   
            }
        };
        void moveRowsSouth(){
            for(int z=0; z<10; z++){
                for(int y=10; y>=1; y--){
                    allStates[y][z] = allStates[y-1][z];
                }
                allStates[0][z].set_values(" ");
            }
        };
        void moveColsEast(){
            for(int z=0; z<10; z++){
                for(int y=10; y>=1; y--){
                    allStates[z][y] = allStates[z][y-1];
                }
                allStates[z][0].set_values(" ");
            }
        };
        void addNeighbor(string s1, string s2, string direction){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == s1)
                        if (direction == "North"){
                            if (row-1 < 0){
                                moveRowsSouth();
                            }
                            else {
                                if (allStates[row-1][col].get_name() == " "){
                                    allStates[row-1][col] = get_state(s2);
                                    deleteState(s2);
                                }
                                else
                                    cout << "Unable to add this neighbor. North is occupied.";
                            }
                        }
                        else if (direction == "South"){
                            if (allStates[row+1][col].get_name() == " "){
                                allStates[row+1][col] = get_state(s2);
                                deleteState(s2);
                            }
                            else
                                cout << "Unable to add this neighbor. South is occupied.";

                        }
                        else if (direction == "East"){
                            if (allStates[row][col+1].get_name() == " "){
                                allStates[row][col+1] = get_state(s2);
                                deleteState(s2);
                            }
                            else
                                cout << "Unable to add this neighbor. East is occupied.";
                        }
                        else if (direction == "West"){
                            if (col-1 < 0){
                                moveColsEast();
                            }
                            else {
                                if (allStates[row][col-1].get_name() == " "){
                                    allStates[row][col-1] = get_state(s2);
                                    deleteState(s2);
                                }
                                else
                                    cout << "Unable to add this neighbor. West is occupied.";
                            }
                        }
                }   
            }
        };
        State getNeighborN(string s1){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == s1)
                        return allStates[row-1][col];
                }   
            }
        };
        State getNeighborS(string s1){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == s1)
                        return allStates[row+1][col];
                }   
            }
        };
        State getNeighborE(string s1){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == s1)
                        return allStates[row][col+1];
                }   
            }
        };
        State getNeighborW(string s1){
            for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
                for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                    if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == s1)
                        return allStates[row][col-1];
                }   
            }
        };  
};

int main()
{
    Area a;
    a.initialize();
    ifstream infile;
    string command;
    infile.open ("proj2.txt", ifstream::in);
    while(!infile.eof()){
        infile >> command;
        if (command == "addState"){
            string stateName;
            infile >> stateName;
            a.addState(stateName);
        }
        else if (command == "addNeighbor"){
            string state1;
            string state2;
            string direction;
            infile >> state1;
            infile >> state2;
            infile >> direction;
            a.addNeighbor(state1, state2, direction);
        }
        else if (command == "addResource"){
            string state;
            string name;
            int amount;
            int price;
            infile >> state;
            infile >> name;
            infile >> amount;
            infile >> price;
            a.get_state(state).addResource(name, amount, price);
        }
        else if (command == "getPrice"){
            string state;
            string resource;
            int amount;
            infile >> state;
            infile >> resource;
            infile >> amount;
            State N = a.getNeighborN(state);
            State S = a.getNeighborS(state);
            State E = a.getNeighborE(state);
            State W = a.getNeighborW(state);
            int countOfNeigh = 0;
            bool stateHas = false;
            if (N.checkForResource(resource) == true) {
                countOfNeigh++;
            }
            if (S.checkForResource(resource) == true) {
                countOfNeigh++;
            }
            if (E.checkForResource(resource) == true) {
                countOfNeigh++;
            }
            if (W.checkForResource(resource) == true) {
                countOfNeigh++;
            }
            if (a.get_state(state).checkForResource(resource) == true) {
                stateHas = true;
            }
            int price = 0;
            if ((stateHas = false && countOfNeigh == 1) ||
                 (stateHas = true && countOfNeigh == 0)){
                price = a.get_state(state).get_resource(resource).get_price();
                price = price+(price*.25);
            }
            else if (stateHas = true && (countOfNeigh == 2 || countOfNeigh == 3)){
                price = a.get_state(state).get_resource(resource).get_price();
            }
            else if (stateHas = true && countOfNeigh == 4){
                price = a.get_state(state).get_resource(resource).get_price();
                price = price-(price*.1);
            }
            else if (stateHas = false && countOfNeigh > 1){
                price = a.get_state(state).get_resource(resource).get_price();
                price = price+(price*.1);
            }
            cout << "The price for " << amount << " units of " << resource << " is " << price << ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking at a segmentation fault. Use a debugger to step through until you find the location it's crashing at. Also, judging by your code, you've probably gone out of bounds of some array. To confirm that this is the case, you can use `std::vector` and use the `at` member function, which will throw an exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You're failing to check whether the file open succeeds - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/open/

In case it does, your program goes in an infinite loop.

There's also no other kind of error checking. When dealing with reading from files, especially data that you expect to be formatted in some way, that's a shortcut to disaster.